# Zsh autocomplete ls command with directories only

Tags: zsh, ls, autocomplete

Suppose I have following files and directories:

```
% ls                                                                   
bui00293    buiawer      builds/     buiowpe/
```

I want to list the content of `builds`

```
% ls bui[TAB]
```

Zsh however shows the options with all the files and dirs above. What I want is the autocompletion of zsh's `cd` command ie. only autocomplete with directory names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you always want to complete directory names only for `ls`, you can put this in your `.zshrc`:

```
compdef _dirs ls
```

You can do fancier stuff with the “new” completion system (initialized by `compinit`) by playing with [styles](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Standard-Styles). Depending on your options, you may need to `unalias ls`. Then, to only ever complete directories on the `ls` command line:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:ls:*' file-patterns '*(/):directories'
```

You can complete only directories by default, but complete any file name if no directory matches:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:ls:*' file-patterns '%p:globbed-files' '*(/):directories'
```

You can also define a key binding to complete only directories, which you can then use anywhere.

```
zle -C complete_dirs .complete-word _dirs
bindkey '^X/' complete_dirs
```

Comment: Thanks, `compdef _dirs ls` solved my problem.